# State update in compose dialog android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dialog

I am stuck in Android compose StateFlow.
I have a project in XML and I am converting it to compose. I want to show a composable dialog from an activity using state in ViewModel. On API success I am updating the state of the dialog which is collectAsState in activity, but I couldn't open the dialog from activity.

ViewModel code

```
    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<GenericDialogState> =
        MutableStateFlow(GenericDialogState())
    val state: StateFlow<GenericDialogState>
        get() = _state.asStateFlow()
_state.update { _state.value.copy(showDialog = true) } //On API response
```

MyActivity Code: (How to cause compose function here or how to define state for composable function)

```
  lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                       
                        mainActivityViewModel.state.collect { uiState ->
                            // New value received
                            if (uiState.showDialog)
                                Log.i(uiState.toString(), uiState.showDialog.toString())
    //                            ComposeGenericDialog(myParameter = MyParameter())
                        }
                    }

            }
```

Please rectify if I am wrong

```
data class GenericDialogState(
    var showDialog: Boolean = false
)
```

Comment: First of all you need to use ```SharedFlow``` for showing one time event like Showing Toast, Showing Snackbar, Showing Dialog etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `SharedFlow` object in `ViewModel` and update its value when you complete an API call or other operation.

On The UI side, you need to collect `SharedFlow` and when the value satisfies the condition it will show `Dialog` Or `Toast`.

```
@Composable
fun Stack026(shareFlowExampleViewModel1: ShareFlowExampleViewModel1) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var showDialog by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        shareFlowExampleViewModel1.showDialog.collect { show ->
            if (show) {
                showDialog = true
            }
        }
    }


    if (showDialog) {
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false }) {
            Surface(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            ) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {
                    Text(text = "My Custom Dialog Example")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Button(onClick = { shareFlowExampleViewModel1.makeAPICall() }) {
            Text(text = "Call API")
        }
    }
}


class ShareFlowExampleViewModel1 : ViewModel() {
    private val _showDialog = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>()
    val showDialog = _showDialog.asSharedFlow()

    fun makeAPICall() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //API call simulation
            delay(2000)
            _showDialog.emit(true)
        }
    }
}
```